# Is "I thought+clause" is neutral in meaning or does it automatically imply "I was wrong".?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-structure

**I thought that Tom was kind.**

I get confused with such sutructures about the meaning, because this structure can have 2 meanings. It can mean **"I thought he was kind and he turned out to be really kind man**, or it can also mean **I thought he was kind but I was clearly wrong, he is not kind at all.**

Without a context or further explanation, you can't decide what it means. And the meanings are completeley opposite.

So, my question is: do such sentences **"I thought+[clause]"** automatically imply **"I was wrong"** or do they not imply anything like that?

And in the case of this sentence, does this sentence only means **"I had the opinion that Tom was kind."** (We don't know whether the speaker wants to say he was right or wrong in his original opinion.)

Comment: I thought that climate change was a hoax, and I was wrong. I thought that climate change was real, and I was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it has three meanings: right, wrong, or indeterminate:

*"I thought Tom was a snitch so was not surprised when he informed on me"* : You were correct

*"I thought Tom was a snitch but was relieved to find that he had kept it a secret"* : You were incorrect

*"I thought Tom was a snitch so did not tell him what I'd done."* : The matter has not been determined

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the tone of voice.

> I thought I had left my book in my bedroom, but it's there on the bookshelf.
>
> (Finding the book on the bedside table) I *thought* that was where I'd left it!